# how to connect to a database created on an rds instance through code in s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have a problem which I am unable to solve. I have uploaded my phonegap  project into  S3 bucket. I have a MySQL database running  on an RDS instance. I also have a EC2 instance on which I am able to deploy the project from my local machine. I am unable to figure out how to connect the 3 together so that I can deploy my app on the EC2 instance from  the S3 bucket directly and also allow the code to access the RDS instance.

Please help.

I am sorry if this is a duplicate but I was unable to find anything which gave me a satisfactory solution to my problem.

Comment: well it seems like you don't understand how the amazon s3 works. You don't need amazon s3 to deploy your code. You only need to put your code into your ec-2 machine.You can do that by cloning from github or just using ftp,scp etc After that from your ec-2 machine you can use your rds instance.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clearing that up. I was under the impression that I needed to put my code in S3 for the rest to work.